# VBA Intersect returns Run time error 91 : Object variable or With Block not set

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I'm writing code that checks to see if a range intersects another and then do something when it does, this is my current build:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim dataRange As Range
lastRow = Worksheets("EvoDbase").UsedRange.Rows.Count

Dim curName As String 'name of current record
Dim curPos As Range
Dim searchRow As Long
Dim finPos As Range
Dim resultsPos As Range
Dim resultsRow As Long 'store row to paste results to

Set dataRange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 7))

dataRange.Sort key1:=ActiveSheet.Columns(2), order1:=xlAscending, key2:=ActiveSheet.Columns(6), order2:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

dataRange.AutoFilter

'find a name, copy the first record against that name to sheet "results", move to next name repeat, move results to active sheet when finished.

searchRow = 2
Set curPos = Worksheets("EvoDbase").Range(Cells(searchRow, 1), Cells(searchRow, 7)) ' set starting position

resultsRow = 2
'resultsPos = Range(Sheets("Results").Range(Cells(resultsRow, 1)), Sheets("Results").Range(Cells(resultsRow, 7)))

Set resultsPos = Range(Worksheets("Results").Cells(resultsRow, 1), Worksheets("Results").Cells(resultsRow, 7))

Set finPos = Range(Worksheets("EvoDbase").Cells(lastRow, 1), Worksheets("EvoDbase").Cells(lastRow, 1))

Do While Intersect(curPos, finPos)
```

When I run this it throws me Run time error 91: Object variable or With Block not set.

I have tried the following(as is suggested on MSDN):

```
Do While Intersect(Range("curPos"), Range("finPos")
```

This gives me error 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

I'm at a loss after looking on stack overflow and other resources, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: maybe curPos and finPos does not intersect each other... also intersect returns a range... try to use it like: `Intersect(...) Is Nothing`

Comment: In my understanding (which is often wrong!) Intersect...Is Nothing means that following code will only if my target is outside the range.

I know you can use "Not" with an If statement i.e. "If Not..." can I use the same syntax with a Do While loop?

Also I am certain to start with they do intersect, curPos starts as a row within finPos.

Comment: Fist: Yes you can: `Do While Not Intersect(...) Is Nothing` will do it as long as it intersects.... Second: `searchRow` is equal to `lastRow`??? `searchRow = 2` but `lastRow = Worksheets("EvoDbase").UsedRange.Rows.Count` which is probably more than 2... (also `UsedRange` includes empty cells and should not be used if possible as the output may not be what you expect => better use the `Cells(Columns(1).Rows.Count,1).End(xlup).Row`-way to get the last cell)

Comment: Still `finPos` has the size of 1x1 and `curPos` of 1x7... maybe a typo???

Comment: finPos size as 1x1 was a typo (thanks for point that out :) )

I'm unsure what you mean by "searchRow is equal to "lastRow", I can't see how that is true?

Good shout, I will find the last row with the method you've described.

Comment: as both ranges only have the height of 1 (1 row), they need to be the same row or they won't intersect... and both work with a variable for the row (curPos and finPos)... that in mind `curPos = finPos` needs to be true or `Intersect` will be an empty range => nothing